# windows 7 crashes unexpectedly whilst saving or restarting

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, freeze

Whenever I try to save my work in microsoft office my laptop takes at least a couple of minutes to save and displays 'not responding', even though the file is small (this happens if I open a document, type one word and then save). I thought this issue may be due to the office version I was using, but it still happens after downloading a new version. After a few minutes the file is saved and all is fine, it just seems strange that it takes so long seeing as my computer is a supposedly 'fast' one.

In addition, the computer sometime freezes if it goes to sleep (i.e. if I leave it for 30 mins), where if I try to continue with my work the program is not responding.

How can I fix these problems?

Comment: This sounds like a HDD problem to be honest.

Comment: Open Resource Monitor and look of the HDD is busy

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds like a hardware error, specifically the hard disk (HDD) and processor.  My recommendation would be to either run some tests yourself using on both peripherals to test their durability and ability to perform or if you are unable to do that, then take it to a repair shop and have them check it over for you.  Word of warning - they (repair shop(s)) may charge you the Earth, so make sure that you are clear on their price before agreeing to anything.